# How to understand the "SIZE" output of the command top on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, top

I am working on a VPS with 512 of RAM, I installed mysql, run the command `top` and found that the value of `SIZE` for mysql is 638M:

```
last pid:  2023;  load averages:  0.17,  0.19,  0.21                                                                                              up 0+03:05:43  19:26:01
27 processes:  1 running, 26 sleeping
CPU:  0.4% user,  0.0% nice,  1.2% system,  0.0% interrupt, 98.4% idle
Mem: 60M Active, 216M Inact, 94M Wired, 59M Buf, 104M Free
Swap: 1024M Total, 1024M Free

  PID USERNAME       THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE    TIME    WCPU COMMAND
 1324 mysql           30  20    0   638M   168M uwait    2:12   0.00% mysqld
```

From the man page I got this:

**SIZE** *is the total size of the process (text, data, and stack)*

Having only 512M of RAM on the VPS, I though I was consuming all memory but based on the `MEM` line seems that not:

```
Mem: 60M Active, 216M Inact, 94M Wired, 59M Buf, 104M Free
```

Therefore I would like to know what more  detail how the `SIZE` and `RES` are calculated and how to  properly interpret them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `RES` column, which is the actual memory (RAM) used by the process. `SIZE` also includes files that are maped by the process (so if those are large SIZE goes up, but the files are still stored on you hard drive).